# MySQL: How to speed up that join?

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables and I need to join them. Unfortunately, I dont have ids that I could use, the only criteria are some varchar column. This is the "on" part of the join:

```
join sales_flat_order_address sfoa on    
   concat(lower(trim(sfoa.firstname)), lower(trim(sfoa.lastname))) = concat(lower(trim(so.firstname)), lower(trim(so.lastname)))
```

I know that this is not the fastest way, but is there a way to spped this up a bit more? Or maybe a workaround I cant think of right now?

Thanks!

Comment: It will be more slower when your table grows larger because it will perform `full table scan` due for not using `INDEX`.  My only advise for you is to normalize your tables.

Comment: Your conditions and data are very specialized that it makes it very hard for us to know what other options might exist. This isn't a very good database design.

Comment: Performing functions like this is inherently a potential performance drag. Would suggest altering tables to include an indexed ID field on each table with corresponding primary/foreign keys, changing joins accordingly, should yield significant performance boost and better scalability over the long haul.

Comment: Wow ... how do you handle the case if two people share the same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use this:

```
ON trim(sfoa.firstname) = trim(so.firstname)
   AND trim(sfoa.lastname) = trim(so.lastname)
```

of course, you could try to index `firstname` and `lastname` in both tables.

Answer (score 2):

Indexing firstname and lastname columns would be a start.

First of all though I would run your query with EXPLAIN in front of it and see if there are any indexes you may already have and think are being used which actually might not be being used.

Secondly, JOINing on varchar is never going to be 'super' quick compared to joining on an int for example.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html

Answer (score 1):

You could add an "and" between first name and last name so as to avoid the concat. Also you can use indexes on these columns (firstname and lastname) so as to speed thing a lot (especially if you use the comparison a lot).

```
join sales_flat_order_address sfoa on    
trim(sfoa.firstname) = trim(so.firstname) and trim(sfoa.lastname) = trim(so.lastname)
```

Answer (score 1):

This query is essentially doing a cross join on the table, and then matching the condition.  To fix this, you could:

1. Add a new column into each table called full name.
2. Give this the value of something like: 
   `concat(lower(trim(firstname)), lower(trim(lastname)))`.
3. Build an index on the value.

Actually, you could do this on only one of the tables, and MySQL will use the index for the comparison (still requiring a full table scan on the first table.

You could also have a "full names" table, and use a foreign key from each of these tables to get the full name.

Indexing the names independently won't affect the query.  The names are being accessed inside functions, which generally turns off the ability to use an index.

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum, you should create an index on firstname and lastname in both tables. Also, run an explain on your query. That can show you inefficiencies.